# how to add value to existing variable from inside a loop?

Tags: r, loops, variable-assignment, dynamic-programming

I want to add a computed value to an existing vector from within a loop in which the wanted vector is called from within the loop . that is im looking for some function that is similar to assign() function but that will enable me to add values to an existing variables and not creating new variables.

example:
say I have 3 variabels :

```
sp=3
for(i in 1:sp){
    name<-paste("sp",i,sep="")
    assign(name,rnorm(5))
}
```

and now I want to access the last value in each of the variabels, double it and add the resault to the vector:

```
for(i in 1:sp){
    name<-paste("sp",i,sep="")
    name[6]<-name[5]*2
}
```

the problem here is that "name" is a string, how can R identify it as a veriable name and access it?

Comment: Only very advanced R programmers should use `assign`. It doesn't seem like you are there yet. For a beginner who is using `assign` there is **always** a better (more efficient and readable) alternative to their approach. E.g., this would be quite easy if you used a list to hold everything instead of creating a bunch of objects in your workspace.

Comment: thank you Ronald but this is just an example, there is no use in printing my whole giant code in here so this is an example for what I need
I think that assign is very goos because my code is composed of many changing variabels that are not all known upfron

Comment: That doesn't mean my comment doesn't apply to your situation. I consider myself quite experienced with R and I practically never use `assign`.

Comment: @etienne that dosent work....

Comment: something like `assign(name,c(eval(as.symbol(name)),eval(as.symbol(name))[5]*2))` would work if you put it in the second loop after the name assignment. But you shouldn't used it.

Comment: this won't answer your question but instead of using `paste(..., sep='')` use `paste0()`

Comment: @etienne why should I use `paste0()`  instead if `paste()`?

Comment: @Aviv : from the help `?paste0` you can see that it is equivalent to `paste(..., sep="")`, slightly more efficiently. Of course, using `paste` with `""` as a separator is not wrong, but `paste0` is just faster.

Comment: @etienne thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is something like this:

```
get(name)
```

In your code it would like this:

```
v <- 1:10
var <- "v"

for (i in v){
  tmp <- get(var)
  tmp[6] <- tmp[5]*2
  assign(var, tmp)
}
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 10  7  8  9 10
```

Does that help you in any way?

However, I agree with the other answer, that lists and the lapply/sapply-functions are better suited!

Comment: no that dosent work, prints an error:
could not find function "get<-
Im looking for somthing that will add the value to the wanted variable

Comment: You are right, I should've tested it before posting it. Thanks for the notification. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this with a list:

```
sp=3

mylist <- vector(mode = "list", length = sp) #initialize a list
names(mylist) <- paste0("sp",seq_len(sp)) #set the names

for(i in 1:sp){
  mylist[[i]] <- rnorm(5)
}

for(i in 1:sp){
  mylist[[i]] <- c(mylist[[i]], mylist[[i]][5] * 2) 
}

mylist
#$sp1
#[1]  0.6974563  0.7714190  1.1980534  0.6011610 -1.5884306 -3.1768611
#
#$sp2
#[1] -0.2276942  0.2982770  0.5504381 -0.2096708 -1.9199551 -3.8399102
#
#$sp3
#[1]  0.235280995  0.276813498  0.002567075 -0.774551774  0.766898045  1.533796089
```

You can then access the list elements as described in `help("[")`, i.e., `mylist$sp1`, `mylist[["sp1"]]`, etc.

Of course, this is still very inefficient code and it could be improved a lot. E.g., since all three variables are of same type and length, they really should be combined into a matrix, which could be filled with one call to `rnorm` and which would also allow doing the second operation with vectorized operations.

Answer (score 0):

@Roland is absolutely right and you absolutely should use a list for this type of problem. It's cleaner and easier to work with. Here's another way of working with what you have (It can be easily generalised):

```
sp <- replicate(3, rnorm(5), simplify=FALSE)
names(sp) <- paste0("sp", 1:3)
sp

#$sp1
#[1] -0.3723205  1.2199743  0.1226524  0.7287469 -0.8670466
#
#$sp2
#[1] -0.5458811 -0.3276503 -1.3031100  1.3064743 -0.7533023
# 
#$sp3
#[1]  1.2683564  0.9419726 -0.5925012 -1.2034788 -0.6613149

newsp <- lapply(sp, function(x){x[6] <- x[5]*2; x})
newsp

#$sp1
#[1] -0.3723205  1.2199743  0.1226524  0.7287469 -0.8670466 -1.7340933
#
#$sp2
#[1] -0.5458811 -0.3276503 -1.3031100  1.3064743 -0.7533023 -1.5066046
#
#$sp3
#[1]  1.2683564  0.9419726 -0.5925012 -1.2034788 -0.6613149 -1.3226297
```

EDIT: If you are truly, sincerely dedicated to doing this despite being recommended otherwise, you can do it this way:

```
for(i in 1:sp){
  name<-paste("sp",i,sep="")
  assign(name, `[<-`(get(name), 6, `[`(get(name), 5) * 2))
}
```

Comment: hi,
thanx but because my code is really dinamic I preffer to stay with the loops technic- a lot of my variabels are connected to one another and that why I want to keep using the loops (where there is very strict varification of variabels name)

Comment: @Roland there is no verification on the variable name. Im dealing with community model (I saw you are an ecologist) and i have many variabels that represents many of the species characteristics. thats why I wanr to keep usinf "for" loops so there will be verification os species variable and characteristics variabels

Comment: what im searching is a way to make R recognize the string i get from the "paste" function as the variable name
example: paste("NO",i,sep="")   will be recognized as  NO5 variable

Comment: @Aviv You should try to understand what we are trying to tell you. There is no reason whatsoever to create variables in a loop and put them into the global environment. Put them into a list. It's easier, more readable, and tidier. Of course, you probably don't need the `for` loops at all, but that's another story ...

Comment: @Ronald I get what your saying but why are you so against the for loops? why is the list way so much better?

Comment: @Aviv You don't get what I'm saying. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Roland
thanx for the example, I might use this method, but I still dont understand why using list in this type of priblem will be more efficient then assigning (by some function Im still looking) values to the variable I want using for loops?

Comment: @Mox, the example does work, but not with the version of `sp` that I defined (a list). It works with the version of `sp` defined by the OP.