# assign values to matrix generated with assign()

Tags: r, matrix

I assigned a matrix to a name which varies with j:

```
j <- 2L
assign(paste0("pca", j,".FAVAR_fcst", sep=""), matrix(ncol=24, nrow=12))
```

I can access a column of this matrix by

```
get(paste0("pca", j, ".FAVAR_fcst", sep=""))[,2]
```

However, if I want assign values to a column I get an error:

```
get(paste0("pca", j, ".FAVAR_fcst", sep=""))[,2] <- 1
```

> Error in get(paste0("pca", j, ".FAVAR_fcst", sep = ""))[, 2] <- 1 : 
>     target of assignment expands to non-language object

or

```
assign(get(paste0("pca", j, ".FAVAR_fcst", sep=""))[,2], 1)
```

> Error in assign(get(paste0("pca", j, ".FAVAR_fcst", sep = ""))[, 2], 1) : 
>     invalid first argument

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You really shouldn't use `assign`, read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805491/how-to-add-value-to-existing-variable-from-inside-a-loop/33805781#33805781) which is quite similar to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign to list index in specific environment using \`get\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830384/assign-to-list-index-in-specific-environment-using-get)

Comment: You cannot use get to assign a value to a variable because `get` is not a replacement function. you cannot use `assign` to assign a value to an element of a matrix either. You could have a look at the duplicate I posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!